# How do I use setTimeout with recursion to wait for a variable to be defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to wait until *`storage.get('session')!=null`*, then execute the *`callback`*.**

The problem I'm having is that **my recursive `setTimeout` method is running exponentially** instead of checking if the variable is defined every second.

The result is waitForElement being executed thousands of times per second which I do not want.. I want it to execute once every 1 second until `storage.get('session')!=null`

```
waitForElement(function(){
    console.log("DONE!");
});

function waitForElement(callback){
    if(storage.get('session')!=null)
    {
        console.log("session exists now");
        if(typeof callback=="function")
        {
            callback();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("session still does not exist. Checking again in 1 second");

        //ISSUE: THIS RUNS IMMEDIATELY AND FOREVER!
        setTimeout(waitForElement(function(cb){
                if(typeof cb == "function"){
                    cb();
                }
        }), 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's putting that variable into the `storage` ?

Comment: Hey @Alnitak! There's a `login` function that will put it into storage. The problem I was having is that multiple functions are waiting for `login` to finish, but I don't want `login` to be called multiple times. So if it's been called once, then wait for it to define 'session'. Everyone else that calls it will wait for login to set session.

Comment: This is the sort of asynchronous situation promises are intended to be used for. Show sample code for `storage.get()`

Comment: You have an XY problem - It sounds to me like you should be using Promises, not polling

Comment: @alnitakl Could you help me with a code example?

Comment: @Kayvar see below

Comment: Do not use timeout polling. Just go for the `window.onstorage` event!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be using timeouts at all - Promises are the preferred model for this sort of asynchronous handling these days, e.g.

```
function login() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // do something that creates the session
        if (successful) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    })
}

// promise that will eventually be resolve when the user logs in
var loggedIn = login();

// multiple (potentially parallel) actions
loggedIn.then(doSomething);
loggedIn.then(doSomethingElse);

// serial actions
loggedIn.then(doFirstThing).then(doSecondThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're immediately invoking the function `waitForElement` when you set your timeout. Try this

```
var callback = function(cb){
    if(typeof cb == "function"){
        cb();
    }
}

setTimeout(waitForElement.bind(this, callback), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are immediately calling waitForElement. You need to pass a function reference which is basically a function name without the "()". Given that your function doesn't have "this" there no need to worry about context for this case.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    waitForElement(function(cb){
        if(typeof cb == "function"){
            cb();
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Also something to note is that you never pass anything into the callback function.